# What is the most functional and ready-to-use SWT API in Scala?

Tags: user-interface, scala, swt

Is there a Scala SWT wrapper/API that has the most features and is most ready to be used? I see a couple what appear to be informal wrappers but can't tell if they're maintained. Also, one or two I see on multiple places and I'm not sure where the canonical place for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been using Dave Orme's [XScalaWT](https://github.com/pieceoftheloaf/XScalaWT/tree/gh-pages) with my own additions for JFace viewers for a while, and I find it great. Be sure to read the very interesting [introductory blog post](http://www.coconut-palm-software.com/the_new_visual_editor/doku.php?id=blog:simplifying_swt_with_scala).

Answer (score 3):

I'm also aware of [SSWT](https://github.com/rodant/SSWT) but have no experience using it. I believe XSWT is more mature.